# over-flow x not working for html table

Tags: jquery, html-table, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I want to set horizontal scroll bar for my html table, but it is not working for me, the table exceeding the browser limit. I added the details of my code below, please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<table cellspacing="10" border="1" width="1200px">
                                        <tr style="border-style: none;">
                                            <td style="border-style: none;">
                                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <table id="tblDetItems" border="1" style="font-size: 9pt; border-color: #A9A9A9;
                                                            position: relative;" class="display" cellspacing="0">
                                                            <thead style="background: #808080; color: White; font-weight: bold; border-color: White;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th style="width: 10px;">
                                                                        SlNo.
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 200px;">
                                                                        Item Code
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 300px;">
                                                                        Description
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 80px;">
                                                                        Group
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Supplier
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Material
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Scode1
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Labour1
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Scode2
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Labour2
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Scode3
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Labour3
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Scode4
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Labour4
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Scode5
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Labour5
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        A Scode
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Assembly
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Replace Cost
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        Total
                                                                    </th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr style="background-color: Silver; height: 45px;">
                                                                    <th style="width: 10px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 60px;" id="txtslno_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 200px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 200px;" id="txt_ItemCode_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 300px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 300px;" id="txtDesc_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 80px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 80px;" id="txtGroup_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Supplier_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Material_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode1_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour1_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode2_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour2_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode3_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour3_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode4_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour4_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode1_tb5" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour1_tb5" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_A_SCode_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Assembly_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_ReplaceCost_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 100px;">
                                                                        <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Total_tbl" />
                                                                    </th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <tr id="tr_id">
                                                            <td id="slno" style="width: 10px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <%# Eval("sl_no")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 200px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <%# Eval("item_cd")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 300px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 290px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    class="fooClass" id="txt_item_desc" value='<%# Eval("item_desc")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 80px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 70px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_gp_cd" value='<%# Eval("gp_cd")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode" value='<%# Eval("sup_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_material" value='<%# Eval("mtrl_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode1" value='<%# Eval("lbr1_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_labour1" value='<%# Eval("lbr1_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode2" value='<%# Eval("lbr2_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_labour2" value='<%# Eval("lbr2_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode3" value='<%# Eval("lbr3_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_labour3" value='<%# Eval("lbr3_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode4" value='<%# Eval("lbr4_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_labour4" value='<%# Eval("lbr4_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_sup_scode5" value='<%# Eval("lbr5_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_labour5" value='<%# Eval("lbr5_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                                                                    id="txt_a_s_scode" value='<%# Eval("assmbly_scode")%>' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_assembly" value='<%# Eval("assmbly_chrge")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                                                                    maxlength="10" id="txt_replace_cost" value='<%# Eval("replace_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                                                                <%# Eval("purc_rate")%>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                        </tbody> </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                </asp:Repeater>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

---

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#tblDetItems').DataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "keys": true,
                "retrieve": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "scrollY": 250,
                "scrollX": true
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

@Reshma, i would say better to use bootstrap , there is a "table-responsive" class in bootstrap , that will solve your problem , please have a look at my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cR3x7m0p1IpRk4z0NhKI?p=preview) example.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table"></table>
<div>
```